# Why all the external modules that we require in javascript(node) are functions?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I imported the modules fs, lodash, yargs and express and then used typeof on the variables in which I required them.All of them except fs are shown as function

1) I can understand if its an object because we use functions residing in that module but all the module being functions are not making sense to me (Sorry if its sounds stupid)

2)

```
const express = require('express');
let app = express();
```

can you please explain the above code snippet(2nd line)?can we store an executing function inside a variable ? are we storing the return value of express inside the app or the entire function and we further use functions like app.get() later just like an object

Second point is somehow related to first and it will be really helpful if someone can explain it to me
Thank You

Comment: Well you could always look at the source code for those modules and answer this yourself. I mean they are open source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JavaScript is a programming language different to others such as Java, maybe that is what is confusing you. Instead it is inspired on Scheme.

In JavaScript, functions are first-class citizens, meaning that they can have properties and methods just like any other object, and that they can be passed and assigned just as any object. See for example https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/First-class_Function for an introduction to first-class functions or https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions for an intro to JavaScript functions.

This is a core concept in JavaScript, thus you maybe want to have a look to some introduction book to grasp properly the language basics.

Regarding the code:

```
const express = require('express');
let app = express();
```

First line is storing a function into a "variable", in fact a constant, express: `express=require('express');`

Then, we can invoke such function using the name of the "variable" (or constant) it is stored: `express()`

Obviously, the previous steps can only be done because of JavaScript allowing functions being treated as "objects"

Finally, we can store the result of the call to the function in a variable as usual: `app = express();`

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation . I think I should read the mdn docs thoroughly

Comment: You are welcome. MDN documentation is great, and there are many Internet tutorials. However, if you need to start with the basics, maybe a didactic approach with a book would be useful. E.g. JavaScript the good parts is a classic

Comment: Yup , I just started reading a book called. 'You don't know JS '

Answer (score 0):

To answer you first question, it depends on what you are exporting from the module, either you are exporting multiple values or just one value.

For example I'm creating a module Math.js to have sum and sub methods and I want this module to return these methods.

```
 const sum = function(a, b) {
   return a + b;    
 };
 const sub = function (a, b) {
   return a -b;
 };

 module.exports = {
  sum, 
  sub
 };
```

In code file say app.js, I'll require and use it as follow:

```
const Math = require('./Math');
const sum  = Math.sum(10, 20);
const sub  = Math.sub(20, 10);
console.log('Sum: ', sum);
console.log('Sub: ', sub);
```

You see, the purpose of Math.js is to return an object containing multiple values.

On the other hand, lets say I want to create a separate module for each Math function. Thus Sum.js as follow:

```
module.exports = function(a, b) {
 return a + b;
};
```

and Sub.js as follow:

```
module.exports = function(a ,b) { 
 return a - b;
};
```

Now in my app.js file I'll use these two modules as follow:

```
const sum = require('./Sum');
const sub = require('./Sub');
console.log('Sum: ', sum(10, 20));
console.log('Sub: ', sub(20, 10));
```

So in the above example, I'm only returing one method per module.

In case of fs module it exports multiple values and in case of express it returns a function that is used to initialize express application.

To answer you second question, First of all understand the concept of Functions are First Class Objects, It means you can do whatever you do with an object,

- Pass it to other function as arguments
- Return a function from a function etc
- Store it to a variable and then call it using like variableName() etc.

That's why in the example code, express module is returning a function, which is stored in express named constant. Then on second line, app variable is initialized with what is the return value of express function after its invocation.

```
const express = require('express');
let app = express();
```